# Excel - elegant formula or IF function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to use Excel to calculate fees, and the fees in question are as follows:

Monthly Gross Income, Fee

- $0-$99.9 = 15%
- $100-$199.9 = 14%
- $200-$299.9 = 13%
- etc...
- $1400-$1499.9 = 1%
- $1500 or above = 0%

I can't work out a mathematical formula for taking x (Monthly Gross Income) and outputting y (Fee). Do I need to rely on the IF function here in Excel, and if so, is there a more elegant way to do it than just stacking 15 IF functions inside each other?

Many thanks.

Comment: You may use CHOOSE but the most elegant is been suggested by @Jeeped,, just below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the amount in A1 try,

```
=MAX(0.15-FLOOR(A1/POWER(10, 4), 0.01), 0)
```

That produces the associated percentage; multiply by the original value in A1 for the fee.

Comment: Truly it's good one +1 ☺

Comment: Thanks so much! Additional question (if you have time): What is the formula for the total fee amount, if the 15% is applied to the first $99.9 only, 14% applied to the next $99.9 only ($100-$199.9) etc...?

Comment: @Chilli,, multiply formula with Fee (`A1,,`)

Comment: @Rajesh, but that would only give me the one percentage applied to the whole amount, not the total of discrete amounts with different fees applied.

Comment: e.g: $250 would be $99.9 @ 15% + $99.9 @ 14% + $50.2 @ 13%

Comment: @Chilli,, this `=MAX(0.15-FLOOR(A2/POWER(10, 4), 0.01), 0)*A2` would return,, 7.8,, is `52*0.15`

Comment: @RajeshS - he wants a whole new formula based on a progression of sums for each stage.

Comment: @Chilli A lookup table is commonly used for that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
=MAX(0,15-INT(A1/100))
```

If your column is formatted as percentage:

```
=MAX(0,15-INT(A1/100))/100
```